# Context changes not show

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

A Simple cart context File:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const CartContext = React.createContext({
  showCart: () => {},
  hideCart: () => {},
  isCartVisible: false,
});

export const CartProvider = (props) => {
  const [cartStatus, setCartStatus] = useState(false);

  const handelShowCart = () => {
    setCartStatus(true);
  };

  const handelHideCart = () => {
    setCartStatus(false);
  };

  const value = {
    showCart: handelShowCart,
    hideCart: handelHideCart,
    isCartVisible: cartStatus,
  };

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={value}>{props.children}</CartContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default CartContext;
```

Implementing Cart context provide in APP js file.

```
import CartContext, { CartProvider } from "./Context/CartContext";

const App = () => {
  const ctx = useContext(CartContext);

  return (
    <CartProvider>
      {ctx.isCartVisible && <Cart />}
      <Header />
      <Meals />
    </CartProvider>
  );
};
```

using header cart button to open modal.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import CartContext from "../Context/CartContext";

const HeaderCartBtn = () => {
  const ctx = useContext(CartContext);

  return (
    <button className={Styles["button"]} onClick={ctx.showCart}>
      <span className={Styles["icon"]}>
        <CartIcon />
      </span>
      <span>Your Cart</span>
      <span className={Styles["badge"]}>3</span>
    </button>
  );
};

export default HeaderCartBtn;
```

On clicking on Cart button on homepage, i can able to see console log.
Code which i wrote to show the cart on click not working.
Please suggest on this.

Comment: If the answer below solved your problem, please mark it as correct so you can close this thread and help other users that might have this same problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

From the `<App />` component, you are consuming data from the context, you need to wrap `<App />` inside the provider as well so as to get the state value. You can put the provider in `Index.js` file:

```
<CartProvider>
  <App />
</CartProvider>
```

This way you can get updated `ctx` value correctly within `<App />` component.

Comment: Thank you it worked.

I understand that where ever we using context we need to wrap to parent and use it.